# Disable directory browsing in Nodejs, Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, directory, azureportal

I'm trying to disable directory browsing in node, hosted on Azure.

This is my root folder and I want to disable browsing.

[image]

The following is my index.js file

```
const express = require('express');

const publicweb = './';
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(publicweb));
app.disable('x-powered-by');
console.log(`serving ${publicweb}`);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(`index.html`, { root: publicweb });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || '3500';
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

I do not want the files to be accessible from the front-end application.

Comment: Node has no directory browsing. If any browser request a file/url, `express.static` checks if the file exists on the hdd/file system, and read it contents and send that back to the client. If the file does not exists, it sends  back a 404 (not found) status. With your "catch all" route (not sure if 100%), you serve for every file that was not found the content of the "index.html" file.

Comment: Thanks, @Marc for making me think in this direction. So the problem here is that my deployment files are listed in the same directory as `express.static` that is why files like `index.js` are accessible in the browser. Can you suggest what should I do in this case?

Comment: I noticed your "publicweb" is the same as the "Curent Working Direcotry" of node. Put your static/assets files in a subfolder like "public" or what you like, and serve via `express.static` only the sub folder. But, it could be possible that on azure a other webserver is running, which expose "wwwroot" to everyone and you have the same result. I dont have any experience with Azure, but im 100% sure, there is a solution to disable the directory listening. Site note: Avoid to serve static files via node and use for that a dedicaded http server, use node only for "APIs/backends"

Answer (score 0):

You can try by creating a web.config, under the hood Azure uses IIS to serve your app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <webSocket enabled="false" />
          <handlers>
                <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
          </handlers>
          <rewrite>
               <rules>
                    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">                    
                        <match url="^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                    </rule>
                    <rule name="StaticContent">
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
                    </rule>
                    <rule name="DynamicContent">
                         <conditions>
                              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                         </conditions>
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
                    </rule>
               </rules>
          </rewrite>
          <security>
               <requestFiltering>
                    <hiddenSegments>
                         <remove segment="bin"/>
                    </hiddenSegments>
               </requestFiltering>
          </security>
          <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
          <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js" debuggingEnabled="false" />
     </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I already have these changes in web.config. But it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

For node.js server,

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use('/your_directory', express.static('./your_directory', { index: false }));
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('App listening on port 3000');
});
```

.htaccess file:
Options -Indexes

Azure:

1. create (or edit) the web.config file in your site's home directory
2. edit it as follows:

```html
<configuration>
 <location path="special_directory_name_here">
  <system.webServer>
   <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
  </system.webServer>
 </location>
</configuration>
```